# How to tell JSDoc that a certain function is a method of a functionally defined class?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Example code:

```
/**
 * @module mymodule
 */

/**
 * my namespace
 * @namespace
 */
var MYMODULE = function() {
    var that = {};

    var MyClass;

    /**
     * @class
     */
    MyClass = function() {
        var that = {};

        var myClassMethod;

        /**
         * what to put here?
         */
        myClassMethod = function() {
        };
        that.myClassMethod = myClassMethod;

        return that;
    };
    that.MyClass = MyClass;

    return that;
}();
```

I want the documentation for myClassMethod() to appear on the HTML page that JSDoc generates for the class MyClass. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `@module` as `mymodule`, from this point the definitions should start from `module:mymodule...` to appear under your module in HTML documentation. The following is the example ...

```
/**
 * @module mymodule
 */
 var mymodule= mymodule|| {};
 /**
  * my namespace
  * @namespace module:mymodule.MYMODULE
  */
 var MYMODULE = function() {
     /**
      * @class
      * @memberof module:mymodule.MYMODULE
      */
     MyClass = function() {
         /**
          * what to put here?
          * @memberof module:mymodule.MYMODULE.MyClass
          */
         myClassMethod = function() {
         }
     }
 }
```

Please note if you wouldn't re-define names in annotations everything should work without `@memberof` annotation. We use the method above with `@memberof` coupled with `@alias` to get the fine control of what we want to appear in resulting documentation.